# Force IE8 Into IE7 Compatiblity Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

Is there a way to force IE8 into IE7 compatibility mode using .NET or Javascript?

Comment: Also, can I accomplish this using IIS settings?

Comment: I guess I could see the value in this for old pages, but PLEASE don't create new pages that depend on IE7...  let the beast die.

Comment: IE8 has bugs that IE7 doesn't have and that go away when switching to compatibility mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070178/why-does-ie8-add-bottom-border-on-my-image-anchor-tag
My site is affected by that bug, and I'd rather tell IE8 to display it correctly like IE7 and every other browser does by adding one line to my .htaccess file, than to add a browser-specific workaround to my actual pages.

Comment: Adding the X-UA-Compatible header also removes the "compatibility view" button, which looks more professional IMO.  The user shouldn't have to figure out which mode is best for your site.  It's the webmaster's job to make the site support all major browsers.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you add this to your meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

IE8 will render the page like IE7.

Comment: You're right - but try to add it immediately after the opening <head> tag. I had problems when it was further down the page.

Comment: What if I don't to add this line to every aspx page on my site.  Can I do it with IIS?

Comment: @Bryan: No.  This is why we use master pages.

Comment: See DDaviesBrackett's answer below for doing it at the site level

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't put it inside `<!--[if IE]>` style conditionals - it literally has to be the first tag within the head element.  That means it is not really a long-term viable solution, as it will force even IE9 into the IE7-rendering mode.  Unless anyone knows a solution for that...

Comment: The other one I like to use as my code works the same for IE 8,9,10 is: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` .  With IE=Edge it will tell IE to use the latest version all the time (as long as you are okay with this...).

Answer (score 31):

You can do it in the web.config

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I have better results with this over the above solutions. Not sure why this wasn't given as a solution. :)

Comment: +1 Good solution, if you're using IIS7 - http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol

Comment: Great solution when you can't change the content of the page or change the page headers directly.

Comment: I think HTTP headers override any meta tags, so they should be the preferred solution if you have the option.

Answer (score 13):

I might have found it now.  http://blog.lroot.com/articles/the-ie7-compatibility-tag-force-ie8-to-use-the-ie7-rendering-mode/

The site says adding this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

or adding this to .htaccess

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
```

Answer (score 11):

There is [an HTTP header](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx) you can set that will force IE8 to use IE7-compatibility mode.

Comment: I couldn't get the meta tag to work, but adding this header did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

its even simpler than that. Using HTML you can just add this metatag to your page (first thing on the page):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

If you wanted to do it using.net, you just have to send your http request with that meta information in the header.  This would require a page refresh to work though.

Also, you can look at a similar question here:
[[Compatibility Mode in IE8 using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934178/compatibility-mode-in-ie8-using-vbscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934178/compatibility-mode-in-ie8-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 5):

one more if you want to switch IE 8 page render in IE 8 standard mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" /> <!-- IE8 mode -->
```

Answer (score 1):

A note to this:

IE 8.0s emulation only promises to display the page the same. There are subtle differences that might cause functionality to break. I recently had a problem with just that. Where IE 7.0 uses a javascript wrapper-function called "anonymous()" in IE 8.0 the wrapper was named differently.

So do not expect things like JavaScript to "just work", because you turn on emulation.

Comment: Writing code that depends on the "name" of an anonymous function is not a reliable dependency to take, regardless of browser version.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in IIS:
http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

Read the comments as well:
Wednesday, April 01, 2009 8:57 AM by John Moore

A quick follow-up.  This worked great for my site as long as I use the IE=EmulateIE7 value.  Trying to use the IE=7 resulted in my site essentially hanging when run on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

my code has this tag

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />

is there a way where i can skip this tag and yet layouts get displayed well and fine
using that tag the display will work upto IE 7 but i want to run it wel in further versions...