# Internet Explorer's Compatibility View breaks my site design

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

My website design is looking fine in Mozilla.
But when I try to run in IE, the design is not looking fine.
When the compatibility view from Tools option in menu of IE is unchecked, the design is looking fine.  But by default the compatability view is checked.

Can by default can we uncheck the compatability view or is their any other problem?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are viewing the website by yourself without using the Compatibility view in IE8, other users are still going to be viewing the website in IE6/7 and other browsers.

It would be best to fix the problems that are causing the design faults so that you are not working around the problem.

If you post your html markup/css that seems to be the issue, I am sure there are many people here who can help.

Comment: I am using JSF it works good in IE8/IE7 but breaks in IE8/IE9 Compatibilty mode.in IE8 it will go to compatibility mode by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The relevant document describing "Compatibility View" is the [Internet Explorer 8 Readiness Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-existing.aspx#compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

The meta tag solution would be a good temp fix until the real cause could be sorted out. However the meta tag doesn't really allow you to control which mode the browser operates in. It seems to simply remove the click-able icon from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Force IE8 Into IE7 Compatiblity Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode) , 
you can add the following tag to make IE8 render as IE7:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

But I think that is is better that you cleanup your HTML so it works correctly in both IE7 and IE8.

Comment: Actually, if it renders correctly in IE8 (non-hack mode) and Mozilla, then you should _not_ force it in IE8-as-IE7-hack mode.

Comment: @MSalters: I agree. But I also wanted to answer the original question of how to do it. I also consider it to be wrong to do it but that was not the original question.