# How can I programmatically disable IE compatibility mode?

Tags: html, xhtml, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have been stuck on this one for a while - I couldn't figure out why a website renders differently in two identical versions of Internet Explorer. Half an hour ago I came across a compatibility mode button in IE which made me really angry.

Disabling compatibility mode has fixed my problem.

Is there a way to disable it programmatically, i.e. from a web page?

**Edit:**

Just came across this blog https://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

I'll post an example code after reading the article

Comment: Not sure if you can do that through a web page, may be better to code for IE compatibility mode (IE 7). :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode. It has nothing to do with the doctype.

Comment: I expect there is a windows/IE setting, but nothing you can do from the webpage to dictate this, since you want to stay in IE8, not go to compatability mode.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want the "old" rendering, and no button to show up on the toolbar so that users can switch modes you can use this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
  <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
```

other options (old and new) include:`IE=5`, `IE=7`, `IE=8`, or `IE=edge`

(edge equals highest mode available)

Comment: Thank you - this works. This still means that I have to change my code to work in IE 7..

Comment: Is there something in particular you have that won't work in IE8 Standards mode? If so, post another question and maybe we can solve it for you.

Comment: It's a positioning of divs. I have read somewhere that IE7 needs extra few pixels for left and right margins or something on those lines. THe site looks great in firefox, safari, chrome, even ie 8 without compatibility mode...but IE 7 is a different story

Comment: Hey, vikp. I've never had problems between IE7 and IE8 as long as the DOCTYPE was specified and its (the DOCTYPE's) standards were met.

Comment: I think @Francisc and Donut (other answer) are right, You'll need a doctype as well.

Comment: Omg thank you. This drove me nuts.  I am a web developer and develop stuff on IE9 platform but when I submit the work and it gets pushed through other things, it ends up all distored on a live side.  This little trick allowed me to force IE9 settings, just the way I see them, getting rid of countless seemingly CSS issues which interfered wtith even jQuery operations.

Comment: If for some reason you can't place this in the head before script or css, you can add it as a header in your web server configuration.

Comment: Thanks @LucasHolt, putting it in the header is the way to go. I just added this to the top of my top-level servlet filter (java solution): `((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");`

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to set your DOCTYPE correctly. Check out MSDN's articles on [DOCTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242(VS.85).aspx) and [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=VS.85).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Please also note that also IE8 browser settings can enforce a certain mode. I have a customer who has IE8 compatibility mode enforced by policy in intranet mode.

Comment: +1, this can be enforced in IE9 aswell. Probably in all newer IE versions I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please add to force IE not apply Compatibility Mode

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by adding the following tag after the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```