# Hack for IE9 compatibility mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a website. Its one section looks the way i want in `IE9` and in `IE8`. But when `IE9` `compatibility mode` is selected the look changes. How can i write a hack for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmaticaly disable IE compatibility mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803901/how-can-i-programmaticaly-disable-ie-compatibility-mode)

Comment: short answer: don't use compatibility mode.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: don't use compatibility mode.

You can force IE not to use compat mode with the following line in the `<head>` section of your HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i added this. But still Its breaking in IE 9 compatibility ode!

Comment: this line should normally stop it going into compatibility mode in the first place.

Comment: Yes but it is not stoping!

Comment: okay, there are a couple of IE config settings that might be at work here. Firstly, if the page has HTML errors, it might force IE into compat mode. Check with http://validator.w3.org/ to confirm. Secondly if it's running on your local PC, you might be hitting IE's "compat mode on local intranet sites" setting. If so, you should probably switch that setting off.