# Force IE 11 to run in IE 8 compatibility mode in ASP.NET

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode

My website renders properly  in IE8, when I use windows 8.1, the default browser which comes is IE11, How can we force IE 11 to run in IE 8 compatibility mode.

I have already tried the option stated in other posts

[How to force compatibility mode for all versions of IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627851/how-to-force-compatibility-mode-for-all-versions-of-ie)

[ASP.NET Project and IE10 Compatibility Mode issues in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149490/asp-net-project-and-ie10-compatibility-mode-issues-in-windows-7)

[Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website)

I am setting in my root web config like

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-UA-Compatible"/>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

If I check the response header using fiddler , it's says to me 
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8

But's it's still not rendering properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want "IE=8":

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

See: [specifying legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.