# browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jsp

When my application runs in Internet Explorer, is needed that it choose IE8 version and run on it. Is there any javascript function that added in my jsp page, it selects IE8 version and run on it.

As in my machine I have IE9, but my default IE7 is the mode it is running. I can manually choose IE8 or IE9 to run on that particular version, but instead I want to write some piece of javascript code that allow any users, when run this application in IE, by default it runs in IE8.

Comment: do you want to detect browser type and version and run specific code?

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but they may be talking about setting the IE rendering/emulation mode, in which case, see the comment by @Pointy

Comment: [X-UA-Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: this is not a good development practice.. at all....

Comment: I can't even imagine what you're doing such that you want to *force* an obsolete browser on your users.

Comment: Sometimes when you are working with ancient sites, some tags are dropped in later browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force IE8 Into IE7 Compatiblity Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode)

Comment: @JosefE.: So you fix the site. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a custom meta tag in your head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8,chrome=1" />
```

This forces emulation of IE8

**EDIT**
On every page unless you are using a filter of some kind

From your jsp filter:

```
((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7,chrome=1");
```

Comment: This works, but it's even better to set it as an HTTP header.

Comment: I agree, that being sent from the server saves you a lot of trouble

Comment: @participantjava I know your pain... T^T May you select my answer as accepted?

Comment: Thanks Josef E, selected..

Comment: Glad to help! :D I also forgot to add that this disables the compat mode button so your users can't really mess up the site unless the f12 it...