# Suddenly intranet sites need to be added to the I.E. Compatibility mode list. Why?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, networking, gpo

As the title states, the problem that I am researching is why users on a domain are having to adjust I.E. setting to include intranet sites in the compatibility mode list. I'm looking for two things.

1. What caused the sudden need to add them to the list?
2. What are good solutions outside of walking users step by step to add these sites?

an example would be:
[Force IE8 Into IE7 Compatiblity Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode)

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: We can't tell you that. You would need to see what's going wrong. Rendering issue or console errors etc.

Comment: My point is that you need to take it off the compatibility list and then see what errors result. We can't do that for you, because we don't have your code. Once you do that, find out what errors there are. Resolve them, or continue using compatibility mode. Providing a comprehensive list of reasons this might happen is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like either the website has been changed recently and became incompatible or users got new browsers or your net admin has changed group policy for compatibility view. You can check what was changed but I would focus on making sure your web site is compatible with default browsers. Typical problems with compatibility mode might be: wrong DOCTYPE, wrong X-UA-Compatible meta-tag.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Yes I'm trying to figure out what changed because the websites have not been edited. Everyone is on IE 11 so I'm thinking it's the server or maybe some update.